# Active Server Pages - break syntax several lines

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

How do I split this string into two lines in asp (Active Server Pages)

```
SQL = ("INSERT INTO produkt_cost_row SET produkt_cost_row_costid = '" & cost_id & "', produkt_cost_row_kommentar = '" & comment &"' ")
```

I want this:

```
 SQL = ("INSERT INTO produkt_cost_row SET
 produkt_cost_row_costid = '" & cost_id & "',
 produkt_cost_row_kommentar = '" & comment &"' ")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the underscore character (`_`), like so:

```
SQL = _
    "INSERT INTO " & _
        "produkt_cost_row " & _
    "SET " & _
        "produkt_cost_row_costid = '" & cost_id & "', " & _
        "produkt_cost_row_kommentar = '" & comment &"' "
```

Just make sure you include a space before the underscore.

**NOTE:**
Bear in mind that you can't break an open string across several lines, you must close the string then concatenate the next section, as demonstrated in the example above.

Some developers find breaking strings like this a nuisance, but, personally, I find it makes the code far more readable.

Comment: Not a big fan of `& _` approach as it becomes difficult to comment out bits, tend to go with the old `SQL = SQL & "..."` for each line, or better yet use a Stored Procedure.

Comment: @Lankymart: Yeah - I prefer SPs too.

Comment: @java: Missed the closing bracket there ... *deleted*.